# How to connect TFT screen (ST7735S) to Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, display, tft

I'm learning to work with Arduino and I decided to work with a TFT display (driver ST7735S, I connect to Arduino Uno), but I encountered a problem in the form that my contacts are labeled differently than in all the examples I looked at (example - no MOSI contacts/ MISO and CLK, instead of BL - BLK), because of which I am confused and cannot connect the screen correctly -
please, help)

Display photo:

[image: Main]

[image: Driver]

Comment: what are the pin labels?... you only said what they are not, which is not very useful ... please update you post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Connections

Connections as follows:

- BLK -> 5V
- CS -> D10 (or anything, i.e. D9 -  just change the `#define` below)
- DC -> D9 (or anything, i.e. D8 -  just change the `#define` below)
- RST -> D8 (or anything, i.e. D7 -  just change the `#define` below)
- SDA -> D11
- SCL -> D13
- VDD -> 5V
- GND -> GND

##### Using TFT library

You can use the TFT library:

```cpp
#include <TFT.h> 
#include <SPI.h>
```

With the following `#defines`:

```cpp
#define CS 10
#define DC 9
#define RST 8
```

Note: if you used different pins, then just change the numbers.

Create an instance and initialise with:

```cpp
TFT myDisplay = TFT(CS, DC, RST);

myDisplay.begin();
```

##### Using GFX

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h>
#include <SPI.h>
```

With the following `#defines`:

```cpp
#define CS 10
#define DC 9
#define RST 8
```

Note: if you used different pins, then just change the numbers.

Create instance<sup>1</sup>:

```cpp
Adafruit_ST7735 myDisplay = Adafruit_ST7735(CS,  DC, RST);
```

Initialise with

```cpp
myDisplay.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Beginner Arduino - Using a 1.8 Inch TFT Display](https://www.instructables.com/Beginner-Arduino-Using-a-18-Inch-TFT-Display/)
- [Guide to 1.8 TFT Display with Arduino](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/guide-to-1-8-tft-display-with-arduino/)

##### Footnote

<sup>1</sup>
Alternative instance creation, which is slower, but you can use different MOSI/SCLK pins (hence the additional `#defines`):

```cpp
#define SCLK 13   // You can change this
#define MOSI 11   // You can change this
Adafruit_ST7735 myDisplay = Adafruit_ST7735(CS, DC, MOSI, SCLK, RST);
```